# php curl GET request executing more than once

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl GET request. It is working fine on XAMPP, when i upload my site to cloud, GET request is executing more than once. What may be the problem. can any one suggest me ? . Following is my curl GET request.

```
    $service_url= "http://xxxmeal.com/get_meals?lat=19.2332&lng=14.3422"
    $curl = curl_init ( $service_url );
    curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $curl_response = curl_exec ( $curl );
    curl_close ( $curl );
```

Comment: ["Could not resolve host: xxxmeal.com; Name or service not known"](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/9Ud7o)

Comment: sorry, its not original address, According to company policy, I can't reveal the address,  but when I wrote above code using php ,it is accessing the url more than once,

Comment: Well in that case enable verbose logging and check for yourself. We can only guess what is going on otherwise and as such this question cannot really be answered.

Comment: kk , anyway thank you, i will try.